# Multiply and add operators in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Is there any library in vhdl that defines * and + operators? I need to multiply and add more than 128 bit numbers .if yes, are they sythesizable?. Please help.

Comment: Yes. Numeric_std has defined such operators since 1993 and have been synthesisable for about the same time. Vector size is unlimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...

  signal a : signed(31 downto 0); -- 32-bit signed value
  signal b : signed(7 downto 0);  -- 8-bit signed value
  signal c : signed(39 downto 0); -- 40-bit signed value

...

  c <= a * b;  -- Note 'c' is as wide as the sum of a's length and b's length
```

The `numeric_std` package defines `unsigned` and `signed` types.  It also defines operators for these as well.  Note it is also permissible (subject to some restrictions) to mix `signed` and `unsigned` with `integers` and `naturals`.  For example:

```
  signal a : signed(31 downto 0);
  signal b : signed(31 downto 0);

...

  b <= a * 17;  -- Multiply by a constant
```

Care must be taken in these cases to ensure overflow does not occur.

And these *are* synthesizable (we use them all the time in real designs).

Answer (score 1):

To @PlayDough's solution, I would recommend to use VHDL attributes to define the vector length of the results.

```vhdl
   library ieee;
   use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...

  signal a : signed(31 downto 0); -- 32-bit signed value
  signal b : signed(7 downto 0);  -- 8-bit signed value
  signal c : signed(a'length+b'length-1 downto 0); -- 40-bit signed value
  signal d : signed(a'range);

...

  c <= a * b;  -- Note 'c' is as wide as the sum of a's length and b's length
  d <= a + b;  -- Note 'd' is as wide as the widest term in addition
```

Using integer constants are tricky, due the vector length of the result is undefined. you should convert them to signed/unsigned vectors before the arithmetic operation.

```vhdl
  signal a : signed(31 downto 0);
  signal b : signed(a'length+5 downto 0);

...

  b <= a * to_signed(17, 6);  -- Multiply by a constant
```